# Incorrect results when trying to find average rate of change from a 2-dimensional list (read from a .txt file)

Tags: python, list, 2d

I've created a program that will read a .txt file composed of a list of prices. The program will create a 2-dimensional list to store the week number, price, and change from previous week. The user will input the desired start week and end week.

If the user were to input the 'start week' as '1' and the 'end week' as '6':
the average change should be '-0.30'
the highest change should be 'week 4' with a change of '2.80'
the lowest change should be 'week 5' with a change of '-4.93'

However, my numbers come out completely wrong.

Here is my code:

```
# get two dimensional list
priceList = []

#open the file
priceFile = open ('MicrosoftPrices.txt', 'r')

#create variable for start year
week = 1
price = float (priceFile.readline())

#special case for week 1

#initialize loop counter
i = 0

while price != '':
    priceList.append ([0,0,0])

    priceList [i][0] = week
    priceList [i][1] = float (price)

    if week == 1:
        priceList [i][2] = 0
    else:
        priceList[i][2] = ((priceList[i][1] - priceList[i-1][1])/priceList[i-1][1])

    #read the next line
    price = priceFile.readline()

    #add to the counter
    i += 1

    #go to next week
    week = week + 1

#initialize start and end weeks
startWeek = 0
endWeek = 0

#define start week validation
def FirstValidation (startWeek):

    startWeek = -1

    while startWeek == -1:
        startWeek = input ('What week would you like to start with?')

        try:
            if startWeek == '':
                startWeek = 1
                break

            startWeek = int (startWeek)

        except Exception:
            print ('Year must be a valid integer between 1 and 52')

        else:
            if startWeek >= 1 and startWeek <= 52:
                break
            else:
                startWeek = -1
                print ('ERROR: Week must be a valid integer between 1 and 52! Please try again.')

    return startWeek

#define end week validation
def LastValidation (endWeek):
    endWeek = -1

    while endWeek == -1:
        endWeek = input ('What week would you like to end with?')

        try:
            if endWeek == '':
                endWeek = 52
                break

            endWeek = int (endWeek)

        except Exception:
            print ('Year must be a valid integer between 1 and 52')
        else:
            if endWeek >= startWeek and endWeek <= 52:
                break
            else:
                endWeek = -1
                print ('ERROR: Week must be a valid integer between 1 and 52! Please try again.')

    return endWeek

def main ():

    #call week validations
    startWeekVal = FirstValidation ('Start Week')
    endWeekVal = LastValidation ('End Week')


    #initialize min and max
    maxChange = 0
    minChange = 100
    maxIndex = 0
    minIndex = 0
    total = 0
    count = 0

    for j in range (startWeekVal, endWeekVal +1):
        if priceList [j][2] > maxChange:
            maxChange = priceList [j][2]
            maxIndex = j
        if priceList [j][2] < minChange:
            minChange = priceList [j][2]
            minIndex = j

        #calc average
        total += priceList [j][2]
        count += 1

        #compute average
        average = total / count

    print ('Start Week:', startWeekVal)
    print ('End Week:', endWeekVal)
    print ('The average change is ', average)
    print ('The week with the highest change is week' , priceList [maxIndex][0], 'with $', format (maxChange, '.2f'))
    print ('The week with the lowest change is week' , priceList [minIndex][0], 'with $', format (minChange, '.2f'))

    #close the file
    priceFile.close()

#call main
main ()
```

For reference, here is the .txt file:

```
52.33
50.99
52.29
55.09
50.16
50.50
51.82
51.30
52.03
53.07
53.49
54.21
55.57
54.42
55.65
51.78
49.87
50.39
51.08
50.62
52.32
51.79
51.48
50.13
49.83
51.16
52.30
53.70
56.57
56.68
57.96
57.94
57.62
58.03
57.67
56.21
57.25
57.43
57.60
57.80
57.42
59.66
59.87
58.71
59.02
60.35
60.53
59.25
61.97
62.30
63.24
62.14
```

Comment: Shouldn't the change between two weeks be the difference of the values?  Why are you dividing?

Comment: You are correct, I just fixed that. I am now getting the correct minimum and maximum values. Still not getting the correct average rate of change.

Comment: What value are you getting for the average rate of change?

Comment: -0.08499999 

In addition, if I press enter on the start week and end week inputs, it is suppose to default to start week = 1 and end week = 52, however it defaults to 0 for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code, I think, should do what you want:

```
# get two dimensional list
priceList = []

#open the file
priceFile = open ('MicrosoftPrices.txt', 'r')

#create variable for start year
week = 1
price = float (priceFile.readline())

#special case for week 1

#initialize loop counter
i = 0

while price != '':
    priceList.append ([0,0,0])

    priceList [i][0] = week
    priceList [i][1] = float (price)

    if week == 1:
        priceList [i][2] = 0
    else:
        priceList[i][2] = (priceList[i][1] - priceList[i-1][1])

    #read the next line
    price = priceFile.readline()

    #add to the counter
    i += 1

    #go to next week
    week = week + 1

#initialize start and end weeks
startWeek = 0
endWeek = 0

#define start week validation
def FirstValidation (startWeek):

    startWeek = -1

    while startWeek == -1:
        startWeek = input ('What week would you like to start with?')

        try:
            if startWeek == '':
                startWeek = 1
                break

            startWeek = int (startWeek)

        except Exception:
            print ('Year must be a valid integer between 1 and 52')

        else:
            if startWeek >= 1 and startWeek <= 52:
                break
            else:
                startWeek = -1
                print ('ERROR: Week must be a valid integer between 1 and 52! Please try again.')

    return startWeek

#define end week validation
def LastValidation (endWeek):
    endWeek = -1

    while endWeek == -1:
        endWeek = input ('What week would you like to end with?')

        try:
            if endWeek == '':
                endWeek = 52
                break

            endWeek = int (endWeek)

        except Exception:
            print ('Year must be a valid integer between 1 and 52')
        else:
            if endWeek >= startWeek and endWeek <= 52:
                break
            else:
                endWeek = -1
                print ('ERROR: Week must be a valid integer between 1 and 52! Please try again.')

    return endWeek

def main ():

    #call week validations
    startWeekVal = FirstValidation ('Start Week')
    endWeekVal = LastValidation ('End Week')


    #initialize min and max
    maxChange = 0
    minChange = 100
    maxIndex = 0
    minIndex = 0
    total = 0
    count = 0

    print priceList

    for j in range (startWeekVal-1, endWeekVal):
        if priceList [j][2] > maxChange:
            maxChange = priceList [j][2]
            maxIndex = j
        if priceList [j][2] < minChange:
            minChange = priceList [j][2]
            minIndex = j

        #calc average
        total += priceList [j][2]
        count += 1

        #compute average

    average = total / count

    print ('Start Week:', startWeekVal)
    print ('End Week:', endWeekVal)
    print ('The average change is ', average)
    print ('The week with the highest change is week' , priceList [maxIndex][0], 'with $', format (maxChange, '.2f'))
    print ('The week with the lowest change is week' , priceList [minIndex][0], 'with $', format (minChange, '.2f'))

    #close the file
    priceFile.close()

#call main
main ()
```

There were a couple of problems, the range you were iterating over was shifted up by one. Which means if you attempted to have a start week of 1 and an end week of 2 it would actually be 2 and 3 respectfully. Then, you were attempting to track the change percentage in the third entry of each sub array and then average those again. Rather, track the magnitude change in the third entry, and then average at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like this

```
def stats(y, start, stop):
    maximum = max(y[start, stop])
    minimum = min(y[start, stop])
    average = sum(y[start, stop])/len(y[start, stop])
    return maximum, minimum, average

with open('prices.txt') as f:
    l = list(map(float, f.readlines()))

x = l[0]
y = []
for i in l:
    y.append(i-x)
    x=i

#We now have two lists.  l[i] has the price at week i, and 
    #y[i] has the change in price from week i-1

start_week = int(input("Start Week: ")) -1
end_week = int(input("End Week: "))

maximum, minimum, average = stats(y, start_week, end_week)

print("Maximum {}".format(maximum))
print("Minimum {}".format(minimum))
print("Average {}".format(average))
```